# Can't update data in mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my admin_edit.php code. I already checked others php file and found no problem. This code has no errors but it can't update data in database.

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php
if($_GET && !$_POST)
{
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    $id = NULL;
}

if($id)
{
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE id_admin=$id";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $hasil  = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
}
elseif($_POST)
{

$id = $_POST['id_admin'];
$nama = $_POST['nama'];
$username  = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if($nama=='' || $username=='' || $password=='')
{
    $error = 'Nama, Username dan Password diisi tidak boleh kosong';
}
else

    {
        $sql = "UPDATE tb_admin SET nama='$nama', username='$username', password='$password' WHERE id_admin='$id'";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['PESAN'] = 'Berhasil merubah user !';
        refresh('admin.php');   
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend> Ubah Admin </legend>
    <?php if(isset($error)) echo '<div class="control-group"><div class="alert alert-error">'.$error.'</div></div>';
     ?>
    <div>
            <label for="nama">Nama</label>
            <input id="nama" name="nama" class="span4" type="text" required="required" value="<?php echo $hasil['username']; ?>"/>
        </div>
    <div>
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required="required" value="<?php echo $hasil['username']; ?>"/>
        </div>
    <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" class="wide" type="password" required="required" value=""/>
        </div>

    <div class="form-actions">           

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit">Simpan</button>

<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript: if(confirm('Anda yakin untuk batal ?')) window.location.href='admin.php'; else return false; ">Batal</button>

<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['id'])) echo $_POST['id']; else echo $hasil['id_admin'];?>">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

I researched this problem for almost half a day and found no solution. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How do you know there aren't any errors, are you checking for them, and if so, how?

Comment: I'll save you the trouble. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Another thing to try is using MYSQL console or Sequel Pro to run the command and see what it spits out on a localhost. Assuming you're running a local database, but still, it helps to at least see something a little deeper.

Comment: @Fred-ii- already sir.
Notice: Undefined index: id_admin in C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\admin\admin_edit.php on line 23

Comment: You are [open to SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1637737).

Comment: It's because your `WHERE` clause relies on a named element called `id_admin` and you don't have one. `WHERE id_admin='$id'` and `$id = $_POST['id_admin'];`

Comment: `<input name="id"...` != `$_POST['id_admin'];`

Comment: Change `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['id'])) echo $_POST['id']; else echo $hasil['id_admin'];?>">` to `<input name="id_admin" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['id_admin'])) echo $_POST['id_admin']; else echo $hasil['id_admin'];?>">` that should solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `name="id"` instead of `name="id_admin"` as well as `$_POST['id']`
instead of `$_POST['id_admin']`

Change

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['id'])) echo $_POST['id']; else echo $hasil['id_admin'];?>">
```

to

```
<input name="id_admin" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['id_admin'])) echo $_POST['id_admin']; else echo $hasil['id_admin'];?>">
```

Your `WHERE` clause depends on it.

`WHERE id_admin='$id'`

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
- Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).